# Svg Wont Display when Opened

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am currently working on a programming assignment where you need to create a random pattern generator. so far I have created a pattern which displays rectangles. But I want to change the rectangles to circles. When I change the tags from `<rect>` to `<circle>` the Svg wont display. I dont understand what needs to be done to change the pattern from Rectangles to Circles.

The code is as Follows

```
 <svg id="mysvg" width="2500" height="1000"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0">
 <script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
  var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
  var num = 100;
  while (num-- > 0)
  {
  var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
     rect.setAttribute("x", Math.random()*2000);
     rect.setAttribute("y", Math.random()*500);
     rect.setAttribute("width", "200");
     rect.setAttribute("height", "300");
     rect.setAttribute("style", "fill:blue;stroke:white;stroke-       width:2;opacity:1");
     mysvg.appendChild(rect);
}  
  ]]></script>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Circles don't have width and height; they have *radius*.

You set redundant `width` and `height` properties but no `r`, which defaults to 0, rendering your circles invisible.

Similarly, instead of `x` and `y`, the circle's centre position is defined by `cx` and `cy`.

So:

```
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circle.setAttribute("cx", Math.random()*2000);
circle.setAttribute("cy", Math.random()*500);
circle.setAttribute("r", "200");
circle.setAttribute("style", "fill: blue; stroke: white; stroke-width: 2; opacity: 1");
mysvg.appendChild(circle);
```

#### ([live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqcpdfzm/))

And get into the habit of simply consulting [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle).

Comment: That Sorted out the Problem. your suggestion was very helpfull!